# On hover expand the button with animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, bootstrap-vue

I have created a button in bootstrap-vue which initially shows a right arrow icon on it and when hovering over, it expands with some text,  everything works fine except my icon and text are stick with each other so I tried to put some margin while expanding the button to add some space in between text and icon however while on hover-off it closes the button with some glitches or not very smoothly because it tries to go back to no margin state.
my code is as below and live code is here at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-resonance-vuecm?file=/src/App.vue:0-623)

My question is is there a way I can make it smooth with CSS?

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-card>
      <template v-slot:footer>
        <b-button id="buttonId" size="sm" pill variant="outline-info">
          <b-icon icon="arrow-right-circle" variant="danger"></b-icon>
          <span>View details</span>
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
button span {
  max-width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-width 1s;
  transition: max-width 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button:hover span {
  max-width: 7rem;
  margin-left: 0.3rem
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

Check out **Hiws** solution, it requires less code, no additional elements and the effect is perfect.

## Original answer

Check out [this fork of your CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-chatelet-p4bji?file=/src/App.vue).

Basically, instead of putting margin on the text you could create a span separating the icon and text

```html
<b-button id="buttonId" size="sm" pill variant="outline-info">
  <b-icon icon="arrow-right-circle" variant="danger"></b-icon>
  <span class="separator"/>
  <span class="text">View details</span>
</b-button>
```

And then play a little with the CSS (i've commented everything that has changed)

```css
button .text { /* added class to distinct between text and separator */
  max-width: 0;
  transition: max-width 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:hover .text { /* as above */
  max-width: 7rem;
  transition-delay: 0.1s; /* The transition must wait until separator expands itself */
}

button .separator {
  display: inline-block;  /* Default span's display type is `inline` which ignored width changes */
  width: 0;               /* Initially it's hidden */
  transition: width 0.1s; /* Probably you will want to adjust this setting. The important part is, keep it in sync with transition-delay on .text  */
  transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Wait until .text .text 'shrinking' has ended. This is overridden if the button is hovered. Ofc keep it in sync with .text transition-duration */
}

button:hover .separator {
  width: 0.3em;             /* that's the 'margin' width */
  transition-delay: unset;  /* If the button is hovered, we don't want to wait with the transition at all. */
}
```

Timing could be improved, but overall mechanism is good to go.

Comment: Try Hiws solution, it looks better and is simpler

Answer (score 6):

While Kamil's solution is pretty smart, i found that if you quickly hovered over the button without letting the animation finish, you will see a weird "popping" since the separator only goes away after a 0.5s delay.

I tried to instead manipulate the padding of the button and span to achieve a similar result.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.details-button {
  padding-right: 0px !important; /* Remove default padding */
}

.details-button span {
  max-width: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: max-width 0.5s, padding-right 0.45s; /* Transition width and padding to avoid "popping" */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px; /* Add default button padding */
}

.details-button:hover span, .details-button:focus span {
  max-width: 100px; /* how far the text can expand, adjust based on content */
  padding-right: 10px !important; /* Adds spacing on the right of the text when expanded */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-card>
    <template v-slot:footer>
      <b-btn class="details-button" size="sm" pill variant="outline-info">
        <b-icon icon="arrow-right-circle" variant="danger"></b-icon>
        <span>Read more</span>
      </b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't thought of that, it is even smoother because it's all happening in a single transition and you have less code to mantain.